# Does MassTransit support observability?

Tags: masstransit

I'm going to implement observability across my projects which are working beside each other in a Microservices environment.

I've used MassTransit and I'm going to track the communication between projects that happen using MassTransit. Perhaps using tools like Jaeger to monitor these communications.

Is there any tools or approach in MassTransit that supports it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MassTransit starts an `Activity` when it consumes a message, as well as publishes a message. It also propagates the activity id across service boundaries by adding it to the message headers.

There's an [article](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/monitoring/diagnostic-source.html) about MassTransit diagnostics in the docs.

You can add the tracing option you want. For example, OpenTelemetry for .NET supports using diagnostic listeners for building traces as [described in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing-instrumentation-walkthroughs). You can then use the Jaeger exporter for OpenTelemetry.

You can also use the OpenTracing contribution library for MassTransit. I have an [example](https://github.com/alexeyzimarev/ndc-2020-talk-tracetrace) for [my talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vl-4OhPyQY) at NDC Oslo 2020, which has complete instrumentation for MassTransit with Prometheus and OpenTracing (with Jaeger). The Prometheus integration library is now a part of the MassTransit main repository.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm interested in what you said in the talk.